# Why my unity android export does not build into an android module?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am working on an Augmented Reality project and I am building the AR part with Unity and then I export this project which creates an Android project for me. I want to get this project and attach it to a native android project as a module so I can open the Unity activity on button click or something like this but for some reason when I do all the steps for the process to happen it just creates a unity module folder which is empty without any activities, classes, Gradle file etc.

Here are the steps I do:

In the build.gradle (project) file I put this:

```
  flatDir {
        dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
    }
```

In the build.gradle (app) file I put this:

```
implementation project(':unityLibrary')
implementation fileTree(dir: project(':unityLibrary').getProjectDir().toString() + ('\\libs'), include: ['*.jar'])
```

In the settings.gradle I specify the location of the unity export:

```
include ':unityLibrary'
project(':unityLibrary').projectDir=new File('..\\washingHandsDemo\\unityLibrary')
```

This is how it looks empty:
[image]

Am I missing something? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this? If yes please help